# How to slice String to two and transfer substrings to different functions?

Tags: java, string, function, switch-statement, substring

I am a beginner and I'm writing a program, which will be a simple simulator of router.

I want to type command "ipA 192.0.0.1" (differents IPs) and want to switch statement to detect "ipA" or "ipB" etc. In every case assigned to command I want to transfer the IP (String) to other function. Here's my simple code. Any solutions? It's not working :(

```
public class Main {

private static Scanner scan;
private static Commands com;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    com = new Commands();       
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){


        String s = scan.nextLine();

        switch(s){
        case("help"):
            com.help();
        break;

        case(s.substring(0, 3).equals("ipA")):
            com.ipA(s.substring(5));
        break;

        case(s.substring(0, 4).equals("ipB1")):
            com.ipA(s.substring(6));
        break;

        case(s.substring(0, 4).equals("ipB2")):
            com.ipA(s.substring(6));
        break;

        case(s.substring(0, 3).equals("ipC")):
            com.ipA(s.substring(5));
        break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong!!!");
        break;
        }







    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can't use `switch` like that in Java. You could use `if` statements instead.

Comment: Okay, I will try it with if statements. Thanks!

Comment: Look at `startsWith` in `String`.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    com = new Commands();
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    while (true) {

        String o = scan.nextLine();
        String s = o.split(" ")[0];

        switch (s) {
        case ("help"):
            com.help();
            break;

        case ("ipA"):
            com.ipA(o.substring(4));
            break;

        case ("ipB1"):
            com.ipA(o.substring(5));
            break;

        case ("ipB2"):
            com.ipA(o.substring(5));
            break;

        case ("ipC"):
            com.ipA(o.substring(4));
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong!!!");
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

The expressions you used inside `case` are boolean expressions. But your switch is based on a String as with `switch(s)`. So your cases should also be String.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the solution with if statements. You can use `if()` `else if() {}` and at last `else {}` to cover all possible conditions. The first `true` result will be executed and the rest will not take place while runtime.

```
package stackoverflow_Question39568263;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner scan;
        final Commands com;

        com = new Commands();
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {    
            final String s = scan.nextLine();

            if (s == "help") {
                com.help();
            }
            else if (s.substring(0, 3).equals("ipA")) {
                com.ipA(s.substring(5));
            }
            else if (s.substring(0, 4).equals("ipB1")) {
                com.ipA(s.substring(6));
            }
            else if (s.substring(0, 4).equals("ipB2")) {
                com.ipA(s.substring(6));
            }
            else if (s.substring(0, 3).equals("ipC")) {
                com.ipA(s.substring(5));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement streaming handling. The main benefit - your code of handling will not change after implementing instead of switch-case:

Class `Action` is a matcher of is your action applicable to input string:

```
abstract class Action {
   public static final Action WRONG_ACTION = new Action() {
        @Override
        public void apply(String s) {
            System.out.println("Wrong");
       }
   };

   private Pattern pattern;

   public Action() {
   }
   public Action(String pattern) {
       this.pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
   }
   public boolean isApplicable(String s) {
       return pattern.matcher(s).matches();
   }

   abstract public void apply(String s);
```

}

Handling looks like:

```
private List<Action> actions;

actions.stream()
       .filter(x -> x.isApplicable(s))
       .findFirst()
       .orElse(Action.WRONG_ACTION)
       .apply(s);
```

`Action` example:

```
class IpAAction extends Action {
    @Override
    public void apply(String s) {
       ...
    }
}

new IpAAction("^ipA");
```